# C++ void value not ignored as it ought to be (Not trying to assign a void value...)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

My question is this:
Does the error appear exactly where the void value is not being ignored or can it appear at a function call that had this error occur internally?

For example, the specific problem I am having...

In my `main.cpp`, I have the following declarations and function call:

```
Dictionary * D = new Dictionary(&dictionaryFile, dictionaryName);
ifstream checkFile;
...
*D->spellCheck(&checkFile, fileName, &cout);
```

The function call here gives the error:

"error: void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Is this specific function call trying to use a void value or could it be within the function, which is defined as follows, in Dictionary.cpp:

```
void Dictionary::spellCheck(ifstream * checkFile, string fileName, std::ostream * out){
    _report.setFileName(fileName);
    string end = "\n";
    int words = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    string word;
    char currChar;
    while(*checkFile >> word){
        currChar = checkFile->get();
        while(currChar != ' ' && currChar != ',' && currChar != '.'){
            word += currChar;
            currChar = checkFile->get();
        }
        *out << word << end;
        word.clear();
    }
    /*
    _report.setWordsRead(words);
    _report.setWordsWrong(wrong);
    _report.printReport();
    */
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `*D->spellCheck` to `D->spellCheck`.

Comment: And that was all it took! Thanks!

Comment: The operator precedence is such that the unary `*` operator applies to the subexpression `D->spellCheck(&checkFile, fileName, &cout)`, which yields a `void` result. `(*D).spellCheck(&checkFile, fileName, &cout)` would also have worked, but `D->spellCheck(...)` is much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

`*D->spellCheck(...)` first calls `D->spellCheck`, then tries to dereference its return value. Since it returns `void`, you can't dereference the return value.

Remove the `*`.